# Convert a dictionary containing arrays to a DataFrame with arrays as strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
d = {name: 'A', 'numbers': array([2.72, 3.74, 1.75])}
```

And I need to create a Pandas DataFrame from this dictionary. I am currently using `df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)`

However, the DataFrame looks like this:

```
name    numbers
  A      2.72
  A      3.74
  A      1.75
```

I tried using `df = pd.DataFrame(d)`, but got the same result.

As I have arrays of numbers that contain more than a thousand values, there's a lot of duplicated info in the DataFrame, not really useful for my intended purpose.

I would like to have a DataFrame like this one:

```
name    numbers
  A      "[2.72, 3.74, 1.75]"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would do:

```
pd.DataFrame({k:[v] for k,v in d.items()}).astype(str)
```

Output:

```
  name             numbers
0    A  [2.72, 3.74, 1.75]
```